# Problems with serializing RxAndroidBle classes

Tags: rx-android, rxandroidble

My app attempts to pass a fairly complex object that uses RxAndroidBle classes from one Android activity to another by adding it to an Intent as a Serializable extra. But I'm getting crashes, apparently due to problems with serialization of these classes.

Is there any fix for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to serialize classes of `RxAndroidBle` because most of them contain references to objects that are not serializable.

If you cannot pass a reference to an object that you want to use in a different part of the code (for instance in a different process) then you would need to create a new instance of `RxBleClient` in that process and use it.

Comment: Found a workaround using, as you suggest, reference to object.